# Installing JDK 1.6, JBoss 4.0 and Postgresql in Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Tags: postgresql, jboss, java, redhat

I have googled a lot to install JDK 1.6, JBoss 4.0 and Postgresql 8.4 in Red Hat Linux Enterprise Edition 5, I tried a lot to install but nothing worked out for me, can anyone tell me the complete procedure for that. I want to deploy an EAR file in the server, I have developed it in Windows, but since I am not able to install in linux, so not working out for me, Would appreciate if someone can help me out...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Egads, don't. They're all very old versions.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java 1.5 (a.k.a Java 5), JBoss 4 would not work on Java 6 without fixing libs.